TeamCity Kotlin DSL Builds Not Triggering Automatically, Pending Changes are detected
I'm using TeamCity with Kotlin DSL (.kts files) to define my CI/CD pipelines. I've configured build configurations with VCS triggers, but they are not starting automatically when changes are pushed to my repository. I have 4 build configurations, two for the dev branch (build-dev and deploy-dev) and two for the master (=default in VCS root) branch (build-prod and deploy-prod). For the latter two the pending changes are displayed in the sidebar and the indicator icon is a green square, for the former two the square is grey and there are no pending changes displayed in the sidebar, but the pending changes are visible if I go to one of the build/deploy-dev configuration pages in the TC UI.
I've checked the following:

VCS root is configured to point to the correct repository. I have the default branch set to master and the branch specification is set to +:*

branch Filters for the individual builds:

build-dev & deploy-dev:

+:*
-:<default>
-:refs/heads/<default>
-:refs/heads/pull-requests*


build-prod & deploy-prod:

+:*
-:dev
-:refs/heads/dev
-:refs/heads/pull-requests*




Triggers: The VCS trigger is enabled to fire at every check in and any file change (+:**) and the branch filters for the triggers are set as follows:

build-dev: +:refs/heads/dev
build-prod: +:refs/heads/master
deploy-dev: finish build trigger on build-dev, branchFilter="+:refs/heads/dev"
deploy-prod: finish build trigger on build-prod, branchFilter=+:"refs/heads/master"


TeamCity logs: There are no obvious error messages related to VCS triggers or build queueing.


Here's a simplified example of one of my build configurations:

